# In Ubuntu 20.04 how do I reset the VNC service's password from the command line

Tags: password, vnc, vino

I was previously able to run the RealVNC Client on my PC and login to the VINO desktop on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server.  But after several months of not trying to access the desktop now all of my user login passwords are rejected.  I can ssh to the server, but I can find no way to reset the VINO password from the command line.

As I recall, VINO had me supply it with its own login password.  The server is 4000 Km away, so I must change its password from the command line.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found this command on the Arch Wiki that looks like it should do the trick.

```
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.Vino vnc-password $(echo -n "mypassword"|base64)
```

Obviously, replace "mypassword" with your intended password.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but changing the password that way didn't allow me to log in:  

    root@TC:/etc# echo -n "foobar123" | base64  
Zm9vYmFyMTIz  
root@TC:/etc# dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.Vino vnc-password $(echo -n "foobar123" | base64 )  
root@TC:/etc# dbus-launch gsettings get org.gnome.Vino vnc-password  
'Zm9vYmFyMTIz'  
root@TC:/etc#

Comment: Could it be that Ubuntu 20.04 uses a different remote desktop program?

Comment: @Rob Rebinett It is possible, but I don't know for sure. Once thing you could do is install x11vnc on the server via SSH,and be able to connect to VNC that way. Once x11vnc is installed, do "x11vnc -usepw" to get a password set up, then use SSH tricks to tunnel the traffic between x11vnc and your system securely. Then start the server. Once that's set up, you should be able to VNC to your server securely.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really need the desktop and I manage many remote beta sites where is problem appears.  So I don't want to install S11 each time this problem appears.